# Question about OpenGL textures, Frame Buffers and UV coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, framebuffer

I am trying to map a texture from a frame buffer object to a triangle mesh flat surface. The problem is that it ends up being black.

Code for frame buffer.

```
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

    glGenTextures(1, &fbo_texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, height, width, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture, 0);
```

So. Where's the issue :(

Comment: *"I am trying to map a texture from a frame buffer object to a triangle mesh flat surface."* - What you want to say is that you want to generate a texture and then put that texture on a mesh.

Comment: Do you bind the default framebuffer before drawing the mesh? - `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);`

Comment: @Rabbid76 I do, yes.

Comment: Do some changes for debug purpose. Separate whether texture generation or primitive drawing failed. e.g. `color = texture(texture, texpos) + 0.5;`

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ah, ok, so when I do that, the surface does show up. Not sure what that means though. Also, the name of the uniform isn't the problem. That's not what I actually use in the program.

Answer (score 3):

The binding between the texture object and the texture sampler uniform is achieved via the texture unit. You need to assign the number of the texture unit that the texture object is bound to instead of the texture object on the texture sampling uniform:

<s>`glUniform1i(textureUniform, fbo_texture);`</s>

```cpp
glUniform1i(textureUniform, 0);
```

---

Your shader cannot be compiled because the sampler uniform variable has the same name as the function `texture`. Rename the uniform variable:

```c
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{ 
    color = texture(u_texture, texpos);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) But, when I try that, the surface just doesn't render.

Comment: @RealName You have to rename the uniform. I've extended the answer.